# RxJava Scheduler from Executor: is safe to create as local instances?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, executorservice

I have a memory expensive task that runs once in a day. And when it gets run I want parallelize the work using Schedulers.

As it doing it's work only once in a day, I don't want to hold Scheduler in class field instead creating it only when it's needed, so they will not consume memory resources + this scheduler is used solely by this task (so it's not needed elsewhere).

Is it safe to create it as local variable? I'm a bit worried about memory reclamations and safety of this action ?

```
private Observable<File> doWork() {
    Scheduler pipelinesScheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pipelines.size()));
    return Observable.from(pipelines)
            // some logic
            .flatMap(pipeline -> pipeline.observeOn(pipelinesScheduler))
            // some logic
}
```

Comment: No, it is not safe. You need to call shutdown on the executor when you are ready with your work. Shutdown will free the thread-resources. Why not use an RxJava-Scheduler?

Comment: @HansWurst I was looking for fixed sized pool, to not overuse app resources.

Comment: @HansWurst what if I move executor to separate variable, and then give it to scheduler and performing cleanup on `doAfterTerminate(()-> executor.shutdown())` ?

Comment: This should do, but I thinke there are better ways to shedule a task when rxjava. I would look into quartz.